# Back Arrow Button In Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic and I'm trying to add back arrow to my project using Ionic framework. I'm using the simple code as follows:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-stable"> 
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
        <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
    </ion-nav-back-button>
    <h1 class="title">Title of my project</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
```

But I can't see the Ionic back button in my header anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some code for header in ionic.

```
<ion-view>
<ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-clear  ion-arrow-left-c  " ng-click="backButton()"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-clear btn-white ion-android-settings header-icon-size " ng-click="openDrawer()"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-content>
    <!-- here content -->
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-header style="background-color: #D3D3D3;box-shadow: none;">
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      <ion-row no-padding>
        <ion-col no-padding>
            <ion-buttons left>
                <button ion-button icon-only (click)="back()">
                    <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
                </button>
            </ion-buttons>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <div style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px; margin-top: 5px;">
            Training Reports
          </div>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col></ion-col>
      </ion-row>


    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: Add some explanation also

Answer (score 0):

`ion-nav-back-button` is only displayed when your navigation stack has more than one page pushed onto it.

The following code shows this by displaying a page and then pushing the same page onto the navigation stack after 2 seconds. In the first page, the back arrow isn't displayed, but it is displayed on the second page and pressing it returns to the first page. The results can be tested in [this JSFiddle that I created](https://jsfiddle.net/bhgq35ya/) (which contains the same code).

HTML:

```
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css"/>

<ion-app>
<ion-nav root='nav-page'></ion-nav>
</ion-app>
```

Javascript:

```
customElements.define(
 'nav-page', class NavPage extends HTMLElement
{
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `
      <ion-header translucent>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-back-button defaultHref="/">
            </ion-back-button>
          </ion-buttons>
          <ion-title>
            Page ${this.data ? this.data.page : 0}
          </ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content fullscreen>
        Page ${this.data ? this.data.page : 0}
      </ion-content>
    `;
  }
});
    
const nav = document.querySelector('ion-nav');
let data = { page: 1 };
    
setTimeout(function() {
  nav.push('nav-page', { data });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: I'm aware that the question is quite old and that a different version of Ionic was present at the time, but the problem that was mentioned and this answer are both applicable to the current version (5.6.6).